# How can I create proper gradient using processing

Tags: java, processing

I am new to programming and I want to create diagram as the picture shown.
[image: Correct diagram]

```
size(300,300);
colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
background(#FFFFFF);


int x,y;
for (x = 0; x <100 ; x++ )
{
  for(y = 0 ; y <100 ; y++)
  {
    stroke (0, x, y );
    rect(y,x,y*3,x*3);

  }
}
```

When I run the program, I get the diagram like this where bottom right of the diagram is missing.
[image: Diagram from my code]

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Yukinakajo, Mady Daby and jstl already provided great answers.

Once you get familiar with `pixels[]` that could another option. You can find an example at the bottom of [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093678/hsb-color-picker/67099853#67099853)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093678/hsb-color-picker/67099853#67099853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the output that you are looking for. You might want to take a look at [`lerpColor()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html).

```
void setup(){
  size(300,300);
}

void draw(){
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
  background(#FFFFFF);
  
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++ ){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
      stroke(0, x, y);
      point(y, x);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is drawing a bunch of white rectangles with varying outline colors. The top left corner of your diagram is what you're looking for. If you want it to fill up the whole screen, here is what I would do:

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
    fill(0, x, y);
    rect(map(x, 0, 100, 0, width), map(y, 0, 100, 0, height), width/100, height/100);
  }
}
```

using the [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) command.